# Keep particular data in a JTable from database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to show particular data that keep one by one data in jtable, but never show all data,

```
 private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {            
    String txt = jTextField1.getText().toString();
    Connection cn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        cn = Dataconnection.getConnection();
        qr = "SELECT p.ProductCode,p.ProductName, p.ProductPrice FROM 
       customer.product p WHERE CONCAT(p.ProductCode, p.ProductName) LIKE '%"+txt+"%'";
        ps=cn.prepareStatement(qr);
        ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a table in database , i want to show specific data  by searching from this table in jtable. but i don't want to show all the data.

Comment: Can you post exception that you are getting? Also, replace '%"+txt+"%' with ? as you are already supplying it in prepared statement.